# Multimedia disambiguation

Tags: morphology, disambiguation

This sentence is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website):

> A website is a collection of related web pages, including multimedia content, typically identified with a common name, and published on at least one web server.

Is the term "multimedia" mentioned in this text a) an adjective or b) a singular noun? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s a nominal adjective. So both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, *multimedia* is being used as an adjective. Using it to describe the "content" that may be included on a website exactly matches the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multimedia) definition of the word as an adjective:

> using, involving, or encompassing several media

[American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=multimedia) also provides a slightly more specific definition:

> **2.** *Computers* Of or relating to an application that integrates different media, such as text, graphics, video, and sound.

In order to use *multimedia* as a noun in this context, you'd probably want to drop the following *content*. Multimedia as a noun seems to typically be defined as multiple types of content, as in the American English definition in the [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/multimedia):

> a combination of media, as film, tape recordings, slides, and special lighting effects, used for entertainment or education